# How can I find all files that contain a string and then replace these files with another?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I want to replace all files (`foo.php` as example) that contain certain string `'bar'` with a backup `foo.php` file, which is located in `./backup/foo.php`. How can I do that?

I know if I `grep -lrI foo .` all files will be listed, but how to replace them?

Comment: You should start using a VCS instead of "source backups". [git](https://git-scm.com/) is a good one.

Comment: That's not necessary. To make long story short: After Wordpress site was hacked, I just need to replace index.php files which were added to every catalog of Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with the following format

**Syntax** :

```
grep -rl matchstring somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

The **example** would be :

```
grep -rl 'windows' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/windows/linux/g'
```

This will search for the string `windows` in all files relative to the current directory and replace 'windows' with `linux` for each occurrence of the string in each file.

**Additional Note from comment** : The forward slash '/' delimiter in the sed argument could also be a different delimiter (such as the pipe '|' character). The pipe delimiter might be useful when searching through a lot of html files if you didn't want to escape the forward slash.

In addition to that you could try [kev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392505/2682944) method

```
cd /path/to/your/folder
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *
```

Occurrences of "foo" will be replaced with "bar".

Comment: OR pipe that grep to a file and use it  (useful for  checking before  making  changes especially on production / enterprise systems.)

Comment: I did like you wrote. I needed to re-make it a few times in order to change strings that were in separate lines. Or maybe there is a solution, that can change many strings at once?

Answer (score 1):

The following line of bash will do, assuming you just want to get rid of these files:

```
   for i in $(grep -lrI bar); do mv -i ./backup/`basename $i` $i; done
```